# repaint in runnable java

Tags: java, multithreading, applet, awt

I read this: http://www.dmc.fmph.uniba.sk/public_html/doc/Java/ch10.htm to help me gain an understanding of runnables and the applet and decided to test out this code. However, within the thread, the repaint() method isn't being called.

```
public class test extends Applet implements Runnable{
    int hello;

    public void start(){
        Thread run = new Thread(this);
        run.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
            hello = i;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        System.out.println(hello);
    }
}
```

I'd expect my results to be something like:

```
0
1
2
...
29
```

However, instead I get:

```
29
29
```

and I don't understand why. Is it because I don't have a stop() method?

Comment: Multiple calls to `repaint()` in quick succession will typically be coalesced into a single call. 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score -1):

Edit:

I was thinking of components, not Applet. Repaint isn't the same as paint. If you wanted to see the loop index as you're saying, you'd need to call paint and supply a Graphics object to the method.

Comment: How would I do that? I tried putting in @Override for both run() and paint() but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: See my edit above. I forgot Applet doesn't have those methods. They're a part of JComponent, which is subclassed by classes like JPanel. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/applet-137165.html as an example of painting in an Applet.